# Camera wake up timer

Tags: camera

I am new to linux and was wondering if there was a way to set a camera to start recording at 5am. I know how to set a sleep for x hours but i cant work out how to start at a specific time.

Comment: Cronjob is the thing you're looking for.

Comment: Actually a cronjob is nice for repeating thing. If it's a one time request, maybe there's a better way. Some other linux systems seem to have the `at` command, but raspbian is missing that.